# RxSwift async task

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I want to start a login task by a login button tapped, after this finished, fetch user order list, shipping address, wish list, other info.
startTask is a button, user tap it, i will start these tasks, but now if the login task failure, user tap startTask button again, i can't start these tasks again, why?
Sample code

```
private func test() {

    let data = ["fetch order list", "fetch shipping addresses", "fetch wishlist", "fetch other info"]

    let fetchInfoTasks = data.map{ asyncTask($0) }.toObservable()
    let someTasks = fetchInfoTasks.merge().toArray()
    let result = login().flatMapLatest{ _ in someTasks }

    startTask
        .rx_tap
        .flatMapLatest{ result }
        .catchError{ error in
            .....error......
            return Observable.empty()
        }
        .subscribeNext{ tasks in
            .....all completed....
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}

private func login()-> Observable<String> {
    return Observable.create{ observer in
        performClosure(afterDealy: 1, onMainQueue: false) {
            if arc4random() % 4 == 0 {
                observer.onNext("login finished")
                observer.onCompleted()
            } else {
                observer.onError(NSError(domain: "", code: -1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "some error"]))
            }
        }
        return AnonymousDisposable{}
    }
}

private func asyncTask(name: String)-> Observable<String> {
    return Observable.create{ observer in
        let delay = Double(arc4random() % 6 + 1)
        performClosure(afterDealy: delay, onMainQueue: false) {
            observer.onNext(name)
            observer.onCompleted()
        }
        return AnonymousDisposable{}
    }
}

func performClosure(afterDealy delay: Double, onMainQueue mainQueueOrNot: Bool, action: dispatch_block_t) {
    let delayIntervals = Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) * delay
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delayIntervals))
    let queue = mainQueueOrNot ? dispatch_get_main_queue() : dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY, 0)
    dispatch_after(time, queue, action)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once an error occurs, the stream terminates. You don't want this to happen at the level of your button, so you must catch errors at a deeper level.

Eg:

```
startTask
    .rx_tap
    .flatMapLatest{
        result
            .catchError{ error in
                 .....error......
                 return Observable.empty()
            }
    }
    .subscribeNext{ tasks in
        .....all completed....
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

This way you can prevent an actual Rx error from bubbling up through the flatMap.

If you need to do something on error, you will probably want to wrap your result in some kind of result enum (recommended https://github.com/antitypical/Result).

An example of this would be:

```
startTask
    .rx_tap
    .flatMapLatest{
        result
            .map { Result.Success(result: $0)
            .catchError{ error in return Result.Error(error: $0) }
    }
    .subscribeNext{ result in
        switch(result) {
            case .Success(let result):
                //display happy case
            case .Error(let error):
                //display sad case
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Comment: Once an error occurs, the stream terminates. Thanks, that's very helpful! May I ask if there're any sources / examples from which I can find related RxSwift practices (except for documentation)?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in `catchError` documentation:

> Returns an observable sequence containing the source sequence's elements, followed by the elements produced by the handler's resulting observable sequence in case an error occurred.

Thus when an error occurs in your login chain, the error is caught in the `catchError` closure and the sequence is terminated.

Here's a sample output of what's happening:

```
2016-05-27 10:03:18.634: AppDelegate.swift:59 (test()) -> subscribed
2016-05-27 10:03:19.792: AppDelegate.swift:59 (test()) -> Event Error(Error Domain= ...ription=some error})
2016-05-27 10:03:19.796: AppDelegate.swift:59 (test()) -> disposed
```

What worked for me in similar cases is to move the `catchError` handler inside the closure which actually does some work (e.g. executing network request) and return some kind of a `Result` enum to handle the error in `subscribeNext`.

Here's the adjusted `test()` function that uses the technique I've described

```
enum Result<T>
{
    case Success(value: T)
    case Failure(error: ErrorType)
}

private func test() {

    let data = ["fetch order list", "fetch shipping addresses", "fetch wishlist", "fetch other info"]

    let fetchInfoTasks = data.map{ asyncTask($0) }.toObservable()
    let someTasks = fetchInfoTasks.merge().toArray()
    let result = login().flatMapLatest{ _ in someTasks }


    let resultHandled = result.map{ Result.Success(value: $0) }
                                .catchError { .just(Result.Failure(error: $0)) }


    let startTask = Observable<Int>.timer(0, period: 5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance);

    startTask
        .flatMapLatest{ _ in resultHandled }
        .debug()
        .subscribeNext{ (result) in
            print("\(result)")
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}
```

And the output is:

```
2016-05-27 10:07:25.507: AppDelegate.swift:59 (test()) -> subscribed

2016-05-27 10:07:26.614: AppDelegate.swift:59 (test()) -> Event Next(Failure(Error D...iption=some error}))
Failure(Error Domain= Code=-1 "some error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=some error})

2016-05-27 10:07:34.878: AppDelegate.swift:59 (test()) -> Event Next(Success(["fetch...ipping addresses"]))
Success(["fetch wishlist", "fetch order list", "fetch other info", "fetch shipping addresses"])

2016-05-27 10:07:41.603: AppDelegate.swift:59 (test()) -> Event Next(Failure(Error D...iption=some error}))
Failure(Error Domain= Code=-1 "some error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=some error})

2016-05-27 10:07:46.588: AppDelegate.swift:59 (test()) -> Event Next(Failure(Error D...iption=some error}))
Failure(Error Domain= Code=-1 "some error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=some error})
```

So as you can see, the main sequence (in my case it's timer, in yours it's button tap events sequence) doesn't error out and you can handle the result in `subscribeNext`. Hope that helps!

**UPD**

Here're some of the resources that you may find helpful:

1. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/tree/master/RxExample
2. http://rx-marin.com/
3. https://github.com/artsy/eidolon
4. https://realm.io/news/ - they have several talks on RxSwift
5. https://gist.github.com/JaviLorbada/4a7bd6129275ebefd5a6 - list of FRP resources
6. http://slack.rxswift.org/ - almighty RxSwift community members:)

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful! May I ask if there're any sources / examples from which I can find related RxSwift practices (except for documentation)?

Comment: please see my updates for a short list of resources that may be useful